# Using an unconnected audio splitter degrades audio signal quality?

Tags: audio, signal

Consider that you have one of the following:

[image: Image of audio splitter]

These are used to connect 2 male audio connectors into only one female connection.

Since I can't find, for now, where I have the audio cable extension, I've decided to connect 2 cables in the female connections, but leave the male connection disconnected.

Will this setup degrade the sound signal quality?

Comment: Yes, but probably not enough for you to hear it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams If there is a difference, I will (probably) hear it. I notice a huge difference when I connect the headphones' cable to the 1st splitter, instead of directly to the computer.

Comment: It depends on the output impedance of whatever is driving these lines. If it's low enough you will get crosstalk.

Comment: @EJP I have my soundcard with the pre-amplifier set to 60Ohms. It is just a simple Asus Xonar DG. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the connection is secure. The stub created by the splitter will have negligible effect. Audio frequencies (approx 200 Hz to 20 kHz) are too low to care about electrical stubs for normal audio applications.

The effects of stubs and transmission lines only needs to be accounted for when the length of the line is a non negligible compared to the signal's shortest wavelength. For audio, the shortest wave length can be calculated to be about 1500 m ([see wavelength calculator](http://www.1728.org/freqwave.htm)). If your application required sending analog audio across 100s of meters (perhaps you are reenacting WW1) then perhaps you would be concerned with the effects of high speed transmission lines.

If you were transmitting gigabit ethernet, you'd start worrying if you line length was more than a few inches. If you were transmitting 60 Hz AC electricity across North America you might also care. In both cases, the instantaneous voltage measured at different points along the line will be different. Having a stub would cause reflections that would interfere.

Comment: Well, the connection won't be secure. But now I have one question: What is the minimum frequence that 'cares' about electrical stubs?

Comment: For the size of the stub here, somewhere in the GHz range...

Comment: @Zulu Thanks for clearing the doubt. Then I think it won't make any difference in the audio quality.

Comment: For the broadest answer possible, any frequency where the length of the line is a significant portion of signal wavelength. If you were transmitting gigabit ethernet, you'd start worrying if you line length was more than a few inches. If you were transmitting 60 Hz AC electricity across North America you might also care. In both cases, the instantaneous voltage measured at different points along the line will be different. Having a stub would cause reflections that would interfere.

Comment: @lm317 It will be connected to 6m of cable + 1.5m + a second splitter, connected with another 1.5m. Will that make any difference?

Comment: It will not. If you're interested in the science, check out this website. http://www.1728.org/freqwave.htm. The highest frequency in the human audio range is about 20 kHz which has a wavelength of about 1500 m which for your application is negligible.